# Python Writing lists to csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

how can i write the results which are in the print statement to a csv file, every time the loop runs the result to be added to the next row. The result contains a lists.

```
def func_high(i):
    swing_low = data_file.iloc[i].Low    
    date =  data_file.iloc[i].Date

    while i < len(data_file):
        i = i + 1

        try :
           swing_high = data_file.iloc[i].High
           if (swing_high < data_file.iloc[i + 1].High) and (data_file.iloc[i + 1].High > data_file.iloc[i + 2].High):
               date_diff = data_file.iloc[i + 1].Date - date
               price_diff = data_file.iloc[i + 1].High - swing_low
               **print (price_diff/date_diff.days, date, swing_low , data_file.iloc[i + 1].Date, data_file.iloc[i + 1].High, date_diff)**

    except IndexError:
        pass
    continue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `print` to `yield`, and use a `csv.writer` (I made a few other edits to your function so I could follow the logic easier).

```
import csv
i = 0

def func_high(i):
    swing_low = data_file.iloc[i].Low    
    date =  data_file.iloc[i].Date
    while i < (len(data_file) - 3):
        i += 1

        swing_high = data_file.iloc[i].High
        curr_date = data_file.iloc[i + 1].Date
        curr_high = data_file.iloc[i + 1].High
        next_high = data_file.iloc[i + 2].High

        if (swing_high < curr_high) and (curr_high > next_high):
            date_diff =  curr_date - date
            price_diff = curr_high - swing_low
            avg_change = price_diff/date_diff.days
            yield [avg_change, date, swing_low, curr_date, curr_high, date_diff]


with open('my_csv.csv', 'w') as out_f:
    writer = csv.writer(out_f, lineterminator='\n') 
    writer.writerows(func_high(i))
```

If you want to go the pandas route, you could do the following using the generator above.

`pd.DataFrame(list(func_high(i)).to_csv('my_csv.csv', index=False, header=False)`

Answer (score 0):

If the result is a pandas [Series or DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#writing-to-csv-format) you should just be using the `to_csv` method.

Comment: so, i would to create a data frame and append the results?

Comment: It seems like you could get that information in a way that would simply produce a series/dataframe. I'm not familiar enough with Pandas yet to know how to do that.

Comment: This is not an answer, should be a comment

Comment: @Merlin when the question isn't particularly good (you know, lacking a [mcve], sometimes answers can be confused with comments. Just because it's *short* doesn't make it *not an answer*.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

df = pd.Series(mylist)

df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

You have to turn the list into a Series/dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a pandas data frame, see one of the other answers that deals with that. If not, using a CSV writer can be good too. However, for completeness, I'll point out that sometimes the simplest approach is to just write the data directly. Not knowing what goes into the data structures in your sample code, I'm providing a simple example program:

```
import sys

def write_csv_row(f, row_data):
    out_str = ','.join([str(e) for e in row_data])
    f.write(out_str + '\n')

def main():
    fname = 'test.dat'
    data = [["Column 1", "Column 2"], [1,1], [2,2]]
    with open(fname, 'w') as out_file:
        for row in data:
            write_csv_row(out_file, row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```